# Работа с CLI в Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, exec

Нужно выполнить команды в командной строке при помощи Node.js. Заюзал child_process.exec(), ОК, все отлично. Пришло время перейти в другую директорию и открыть приложение. Запускаем "cd" а затем нужную нам команду. Не получается, ведь после первой команды процесс закрывается. Хорошо, мы конечно же знаем что можно указать место, где команда будет выполнена:

```
exec("lol.exe", {cwd:"desktop/lol/"}, ...)
```

Но этот вариант для меня неприемлемый. Возможно есть способ из node.js запустить командную строку и отправлять в неё команды?

Comment: А командная строка в какой ОС и какая?

Comment: ну судя по тому что lol.exe это винда, и уж явно не 95/98, а значит 99% это Win7 и выше, а они по сути одинаковы, по крайне мере в шеле

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что мешает запустить CMD.exe и просто передавать туда команды и читать через стандартный ввод-вывод ????? или так тоже не подходит

например как то так

```
 var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('cmd.exe');
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
child.stdin.write("dir\n");
child.stdin.write("cd ..\n");
child.stdin.write("tdm-gcc-5.1.0-3.exe\n");
```

У меня всё работает "tdm-gcc-5.1.0-3.exe" лежит на директорию выше чем запускается скрипт

Comment: Не могли бы вы показать пример кода, который это делает?

Comment: пример кода сделал

Answer (score 0):

> Запускаем "cd" а затем нужную нам команду.

А почему бы самим не перейти в нужную директорию?

```
process.chdir(path);
child_process.execFile(cmd, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Запускаем "cd" а затем нужную нам команду. Не получается, ведь после первой команды процесс закрывается.

В консоли можно выполнять несколько команд последовательно, как одно целое. Например:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('cd a\\test\\path && lol.exe', function() {
    // ... do something cool here.
});
```

А вообще, если нужно что-то более сложное, то лучше порождать процесс командной строки, например так, как описано в ответе @vnn198 .

Answer (score 0):

Природа консоли/командной строки синхронна и последовательна. Ребята сделали для нашего с вами удобства отличную синхронную штуку [shelljs](https://github.com/arturadib/shelljs) Можно использовать короткие адаптированные команды или `exec`

```
cd('lib');

if (exec('git commit -am "Auto-commit"').code !== 0) {
  echo('Error: Git commit failed');
  exit(1);
}
```

К тому же - ShellJS is a portable (**Windows/Linux/OS X**) implementation of Unix shell commands on top of the Node.js API.